# Building custom kernel for signed vmlinuz

Tags: kernel, uefi, compiling

I am building kernel from source(4.15) and want a signed vmlinuz (vmlinuz.efi.signed). How can I build one?

Answer (score 1):

For installation on EFI boot systems, vmulinuz has to be signed by a private key.  To do this, install the `sbsigntool` package.  You will also need to make keys with `openssl` and add your public key to the MOK list.  I'm far from an expert on this since I've only done it once, but hopefully [this](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) gets you on track.